Probability of $r$ consecutive heads occurring exactly once in infinite tosses
I was thinking about this problem:

In an infinite number of tosses, what is the probability of exactly $r$ consecutive heads exactly once if the probability of a head in a single toss is $p$?

My reformulation to the above problem is as follows:

Start with a biased coin with a probability of head equal to $p$. Define a game with the objective of obtaining $r$ consecutive heads. The game stops when the objective is completed. What is the probability of the game stopping?

First question: Is the above reformulation, correct?
If this is correct, then my approach to solving the problem is as follows:

In the figure, we have a random walk with states from $0$ to $r$ and each state $k$ denotes the event of having exactly $k$ consecutive heads. The probability of transitioning from state $k-1$ to state $k$ is $p$ for $k \in \{0, 1, \dots, r\}$ and at each state if you obtain a tail w.p. $1-p$ then you go back to the starting state $0$. The objective is to calculate the steady state probabilities of each state, specifically the state $r$.
At time $t = 0$, the random walker may either be in state $0$ or state $1$ but not in any other state. About the initial probabilities of these two states we may say the following:
\begin{equation}
P(0) = \frac{1}{2}, \qquad P(1) = \frac{3}{4}
\end{equation}
where the second one follows from the fact that the random walker is initially at state $1$ w.p. $1/2$ if they have a tossed a head to start with or it is at state $1$ coming from state $0$ w.p. $1/2\cdot P(0) = 1/4$.
However, I am unable to find the stationary distribution of the random walk above. I don't even know if a stationary distribution exists for the above formulation.
Any help is greatly appreciated.
EDIT: I had an idea about why the probability cannot be $1$. It may be vague and completely wrong, but I am just curious. My initial thought was since there are infinite tosses, so any pattern string has to come in at least one toss. Thus, the probability has to be 1. However, if we index the tosses with numbers then owing to the fact that there are infinite tosses, the index set is $\mathbb{N}$. But if we were to order the outcomes of the infinitely many tosses then there is the bijection from this set to $2^{\mathbb{N}}$. For a finite number of tosses, $n$ all this means is that the total number of outcomes is $2^n$. Now since $\vert 2^{\mathbb{N}} \vert > \vert \mathbb{N} \vert$, it is simply not possible to accommodate all possible outcomes even in infinite tosses since the latter is a lesser infinity.
This is my gross idea as of now for why the probability cannot be $1$. Please comment or respond if you find any bugs in the question or in my idea.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

To answer the first question being asked in the post: no, the reformulation is not equivalent—in part because the original question asks for a probability, while the reformulation sets up a game but doesn't ask a question about it.
In an infinite sequence of identically distributed independent tosses (with $0<p<1$ strictly), every finite configuration will occur infinitely often with probability $1$. So the answer to the original question is "$0$".
The argument near the end of the post is erroneous because we haven't been careful about what objects we're considering. The error might be clearer in this parallel version: In $3$ tosses, there are $2^3=8$ possible outcomes; but since $2^3>3$, it's impossible to represent all $8$ outcomes with only $3$ tosses.

Thanks, @GregMartin for the generous response. At the end, my argument is not about "representing" but accommodating all 8 outcomes in 3 tosses. Also is it possible to find the probability in a finite setting and let $lim_{n\to\infty}$ to see if it goes to $0$?

As it stands, your question can't be answered until it has been formulated precisely. I recommend rigorously defining the mathematical objects you're thinking about and making an explicit assertion about those mathematical objects.

As @aschepler pointed out, the reformulation is not correct. I do not have any other reformulations in my mind. The question stands as it is in the primal form. My curiosity is to solve both questions (the original one and the false reformulation). Is it possible to solve them analytically?
